# How to implement the pull-down refresh and pull-up loading more functions of this picture？

Tags: flutter

[image: my picture]

I use `NestedScrollView+TabBar+TabBarView` to achieve this Ui effect, I want the entire page to be refreshed with pull-down and load more with pull-up, but I don’t know how to achieve it?
This page is implemented with flutter。The title in this red box needs to be suspended during the scrolling process.

Comment: What have you tried so far? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

To detect if a user pulls down to refresh content you can wrap a widget with a [RefreshIndicator](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RefreshIndicator-class.html).

> load more with pull-up

I think you are looking to implement an infinite scrolling pagination. [I found a resource that might help you out with that.](https://www.raywenderlich.com/14214369-infinite-scrolling-pagination-in-flutter)